# limited number of results fetched from FQL when quering user's wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

i am new here and i am now developing a Facebook app which needs to read the wall posts of a user. After reading the Facebook documentation i found that i should use FQL to do it. Therefore i issued the following request: 
`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT post_id , message FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND actor_id != me()  AND created_time > 1221596000 &access_token=...`

This should return all of the posts on my wall from others before the time 1221596000, which is in year 2008. However, what i get is just a small bunch of wall posts which is posted today, not even recent posts like the ones from last week. I have checked that my access token have the permission read_stream.

I have read other posts here that this is a limitation for FQL which the results may not be accurate. But i cannot really believe this. Is there anything i missed?

I am frustrated now. If FQL really can't helps what other way can i use to read the wall posts? I am using PHP for my app.

Thanks in advance. :-)